# carousel loading from separate html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to web programming so please excuse me.

I have a div in my index.html file, which is empty .

```
<div id='menu1'  >
</div><!--/.well -->
```

based on menu item clicks I load html files in side the div.

```
$('#menu1').load('gallery.html')
```

So gallery.html has twitter bootstrap example carousel but its not getting loaded, however if I paste the code directly to index.html's "menu1" div, everything seems to be working.

any suggestions will be helpful.

EDIT*** my js [which calls the loading of slider]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            //$('#menu1').load('home.html')

            $("li").click(function(){
          // If this isn't already active
          if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            // Remove the class from anything that is active
            $("li.active").removeClass("active");
            // And make this active
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });


            $('ul li a').live('click', function() {

                var clickid = $(this).parent('li').index();
                var myid = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#menu1').html(" ");
                $('#slider').css('display','none');
                switch (myid)
                {
                    case "home":
                    $('#slider').css('display','block');
                    break;
                    case "aboutus":
                    $('#menu1').load('aboutus.html')
                    break;
                                case "gallery":
                    $('#menu1').load('gallery.html')
                    break;

                };
    //alert(myid);
                //alert(clickid);

            });
        });
```

EDIT** html code of gallery.html [the slider I am talking about]

```
<div id = "myCarousel" class="carousel">
    <!-- Carousel items -->

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="../photos/1.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Super sweet bathroom</h4>
            <p>This bathroom is truly incredible</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="../photos/2.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>OK, maybe this bathroom is better</h4>
          <p>This beautiful bathroom could be yours - just call Price Builders today.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="../photos/3.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>Not even sure what this is</h4>
          <p>Go figure</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
  </div>
```

the image slider from the gallery.html gets loaded but it doesnot work.. I cant move images.. however same works if i move the code to index.html and not load using js

Comment: are you sure that gallery.html and index.html is in the same folder?

Comment: try to add `alert(myid)` next to your `load` command see if it gets alerted

Comment: yes it does the page gets loaded

Comment: well if page gets loaded i see no problem anymore, or am i wrong?

Comment: page is loaded I can see one image and right left arrow but slider does not work

Comment: what slider? could you perhaps give me your page link?

Comment: I have added the html code too

Comment: hmm well i can see that right before switch you run this command: `$('#slider').css('display','none');` and so your slider stays hidden until you click on `home` so perhaps you should add `$('#slider').css('display','block');` to gallery `case` aswell?

Comment: this slider is different its on my home page and working fine , its not related to what I am having trouble with.

Comment: Okay then, please clarify what problem are you having exactly? Because you have said that `page gets loaded ` and now you said that slider loads aswell, so what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: the image slider from the gallery.html gets loaded but it doesnot work.. I cant move images.. however same works if i move the code to index.html and not load using js

Comment: @RohitBhatnagar post the js where you make call to your slider.

Comment: In this case please read phazorRise answer, i don't know you might be not aware of it, but whatever slider you are talking about is probably using some script from the other place, so when you include that `gallery.html` file you need to "rerun" that script otherwise it won't wor

Comment: You are missing something here. The code you've mentioned is a switch case to load file. And `gallery.html` contains only markup of elements. You are missing from where the slider get initilised. Atleast post the link from where you picked up  the slider.

Answer (score 0):

From above comments i get to know that `gallery.html` gets included in your page but slider isn't working. If that is the case, then I assume you've called your slider script from your main file ( one from which you load other files ). In this scenario, newly loaded elements can not get attached to your slider script since they are loaded later. You can use, http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ or http://api.jquery.com/live/

The reason, i suggest you to use jQuery is, it gets simpler to do certain complex and/or difficult tasks with easier approach.

you said,

> the image slider from the gallery.html gets loaded but it doesnot work.. I cant move images.. however same works if i move the code to index.html and not load using js.

Post that index.html.

Comment: He is already using jquery, and it's quite hard to understand what kind of slider doesn't work but i hope you're right

Comment: yes, he should better include the code of slider he is mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

```
    case "gallery":
            $('#menu1').load('gallery.html');
            //call code for carousel here
            //eg: $( "#myCarousel" ).carousel();
            break;
```

The issue is, when the carousel is assigned in the begining, such a div doesnot exist, and thus fails. Later once div is appended, it is not assigned to the carousel. No probs, this can be done after the case gallery is called.